# Multiple columns from one table rely on one single table

Tags: postgresql, database-design, relational-theory, postgresql-9.2, relations

I'm working with PostgreSQL 9.2 and have the following relation between 2 tables:

[image]

The table `town` stores a list of town codes. The table `perimeter` stores perimeters denomination. Towns are almost always included in the same waste water and drinking water perimeters. But a few ones can be included in a waste water perimeter different from the drinking water one.

**Table `town`:**

```
t_code  | t_waste_water | t_drinking_water
--------+---------------+------------------
 001    | 01            | 01
 002    | 02            | 02
 003    | 01            | 03
 004    | 02            | 02
 005    | 01            | 01
```

**Table `perimeter`:**

```
perim_code | perim_name
-----------+------------
 01        | North
 02        | West
 03        | East
```

For instance, town `003`is included in the North perimeter for waste water and to the East perimeter for drinking water stuff. Perimeters having the same names for waste water or drinking water concerns, I have put them in a single central table, instead of duplicating informations into one waste water table and one drinking water table.

Now, I would like to get perimeters' names together with town code in a single table, as bellow:

```
town    | perim_waste_water | perim_drinking_water
--------+-------------------+------------------
 001    | North             | North
 002    | West              | West
 003    | North             | East
```

My problem is that I don't see how to display more than one perimeter name for I can specify one relation (JOIN) between the two tables. The following query is not usefull but is a start...

```
SELECT 
  a.t_code,
  a.t_waste_water,
  a.t_drinking_water,
  b.perim_name AS waste_water_perim,
  b.perim_name AS drinking_water_perim

FROM schema.town a
  LEFT JOIN schema.perimeter b ON a.t_waste_water = b.perim_code AND a.t_drinking_water = b.perim_code;
```

Is there a solution inside the query or do I have to structure data differently in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use two JOINs here but I think that this will work. You can join on the same table multiple times

```
SELECT 
  a.t_code,
  a.t_waste_water,
  a.t_drinking_water,
  b.perim_name AS waste_water_perim,
  c.perim_name AS drinking_water_perim

FROM schema.town a
  JOIN schema.perimeter b ON a.t_waste_water = b.perim_code 
  JOIN schema.perimeter c ON a.t_drinking_water = c.perim_code;
```